# how to remove duplicacy in database when importing csv file into app that using spree gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, rubygems, spree, mysql2

i am using spree gem in my app. I import products from product_controller_decorator.rb using csv file.Three tables like spree_products,spree_variants and
spree_prices are relation. As @prod.save happen then it create one row in spree_products,one in spree_variants and one in spree_prices. then another 
spree_variants and spree_prices row form due to @var and @price for corresponding @prod which create duplicacy in both table.This is happens due to
 association among three tables.can any one resolve this complicacy.It means it form one row to each table.

```
def import

    require 'csv'
    file = params[:file]
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true, encoding:'iso-8859-1:utf-8') do |row|

   @prod = Spree::Product.new()
   @prod.name = row["name"]
   @prod.shipping_category_id = row["shipping_category_id"]
   @prod.description = row["description"]
   @prod.available_on = row["available_on"]
   @prod.meta_description = row["meta_description"]
   @prod.meta_keywords = row["meta_keywords"]
   @prod.tax_category_id = row["tax_category_id"]
   @prod.shipping_category_id = row["shipping_category_id"]
   @prod.promotionable = row["promotionable"]
   @prod.meta_title = row["meta_title"]
   @prod.featured = row["featured"]
   @prod.supplier_id = row["supplier_id"]
   @prod.master.price = row["master_price"]
   @prod.save!

   @var = Spree::Variant.create(cost_price: row["cost_price"], is_master:1, product_id: @prod.id, sku: row["sku"])
   if @var.errors.present?
           render json: @var   #.errors and return
   end

   @price = Spree::Price.create(variant_id: @var.id)
   if @price.errors.present?
           render json: @price #.errors and return
   end

end
   redirect_to admin_products_path, notice: "products imported."
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Spree, the master is created when the product is saved, and the defaults for master is applied to it.  Instead of creating a new master variant, `@var = Spree::Variant.create`, update the master instead.  You update the master earlier in the file by assigning `@prod.master.price = row["master_price"]`.  That code isn't failing because master is created with default values before the call to `@product.save`.  The line `@price = Spree::Price.create(variant_id: @var.id)` Is associating an empty (default) Price with the @prod.master.  That is already done, they are supposed to be unique, so there is probably fallout from doing this.

Avoid checking for errors after executing `.create`.  If you want to validate errors, do so before saving.  The way to do this is:

```
@var = Spree::Variant.new(cost_price: row["cost_price"], is_master:1, product_id: @prod.id, sku: row["sku"])
if @var.errors.present?
       render json: @var   #.errors and return
else @var.save
```

I would rewrite the block as this:

```
 @prod = Spree::Product.new()
 @prod.name = row["name"]
 @prod.shipping_category_id = row["shipping_category_id"]
 @prod.description = row["description"]
 @prod.available_on = row["available_on"]
 @prod.meta_description = row["meta_description"]
 @prod.meta_keywords = row["meta_keywords"]
 @prod.tax_category_id = row["tax_category_id"]
 @prod.shipping_category_id = row["shipping_category_id"]
 @prod.promotionable = row["promotionable"]
 @prod.meta_title = row["meta_title"]
 @prod.featured = row["featured"]
 @prod.supplier_id = row["supplier_id"]
 @prod.master.price = row["master_price"]
 @prod.master.sku = row["sku"]

 [@prod, @prod.master, @prod.master.price].each do |obj|
   render json: obj if obj.errors.present?
 end
 @prod.save!
```

Here is the spree-core source: [Spree Product Model](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/app/models/spree/product.rb)

Comment: if it works, check the box please, that way  other people can find the answers too.